# Checking in the AjaxControlToolkit Via Source Control

Tags: version-control, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've installed the latest AjaxControlToolkit and everything's working fine and dandy.

When I go to check-in my changes none of the ACT stuff is ticked for check-in but any pages I have edited have been ticked.

Is there a specific reason for this? Should I not check it in?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly some quirk of your source control provider.

Personally, I like to include everything (non-standard) required to build the solution in SVN.

For AjaxControlToolkit, I use Nuget.exe, packages.config containing a line relating to a specific version of AjaxControlToolkit, and a pre-build event to automate downloading the correct version of the toolkit just before the build.

This way, you get to tie a specific revision of your work in source control to a specific version of the toolkit, without having to check binaries in to source control (bad practice).

Comment: Ah, maybe that's the reason it doesn't auto select the toolkit to check in. Because of the DLLs. So why is it a bad idea to check those in?

Comment: Source control systems are meant primarily for storing text-based data. Modern source control systems can generally properly handle binary files (i.e. only store differences between versions, not the whole file regardless of how much has changed), so this will probably work fine, but I'd still say it has a bad smell to it.